# What to do with [psychology] and [learning]?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are currently 55 [questions](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psychology) tagged [psychology](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psychology)

> Psychological studies based on infant, toddler, and adolescent behavior or parenting techniques and disciplinary action. Appropriate questions should relate to a study or finding in a psychological study or should deal with wanting information about certain behavior or using parenting techniques based on peer-reviewed, scholarly research by doctors of psychology.

There are currently 86 [questions](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning) tagged [learning](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning)

> The psychological process by which children gain and retain knowledge. For questions on how to teach, please see the "Teaching" tag. For more general questions on providing information and instruction, see the "Education" tag. For questions specific to a school environment, see the "School" tag.

Both tags are from early 2011, so already pretty old.

Stack Exchange got another beta site, [Psychology & Neuroscience Beta](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

It strikes me as odd that both tags seem to be geared towards questions on topic on Psychology & Neuroscience Beta, while they are maybe not so useful here.

- [psychology](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psychology) is to some extent a synonym of [research](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research).
- Both tags are often misused, e. g. [learning](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning) as a synonym of *education* or *teaching*, while [psychology](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psychology) is used as a synonym of [behavior](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/behavior).

I want to discuss what to dow with these tags.

Do we need them (both)? If so, do we need to change their scope? Or should they be removed and become synonyms of the tags most often confused with?

For example, could [psychology](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/psychology) often be covered by [behavior](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/behavior) and [research](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/research)? Is the usage of [learning](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning) too counter-intuitive ("I want my child to learn this or that, hence I tag it [learning](https://parenting.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning)")?

Comment: Good question! I'm interested to see what the community thinks.